# How to use mods in newer versions of Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

When Minecraft updates (It recently updated to 1.8) Minecraft mods no longer work. I have tried setting the Minecraft game back to an earlier version but most of the mods do not work anymore.

Do the mods need to be updated to work with the newest system regardless of updates? Or can mods remain the same and the Minecraft client just need to allow mods to be readmitted into the file system?

Comment: You should be able to set your game profile to your forge profile. That should do it. If not, you might need to reinstall Minecraft Forge.

Answer (score 0):

All mods will need to be updated to work with Minecraft 1.8, and very few have been yet. On the mod's page, it will tell you what version the mod will work with.